# Styling drop down menu elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the drop down level of my navigation (for example, increase the width of the drop down), but can't find the relevant selector to change. The site is http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2

Example: On the "New Motorcycles" drop down, I would like to increase the width, and then move the rollover elements to the side

I know the code to use, but I just can't find the relevant selector to do it under. Tearing my hair out here!

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help? http://jsfiddle.net/Xtu9t/

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Motorcycles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Adventure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">125cc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foofoo</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">subsub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">subsub2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Used motorcycles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Motor 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Motor 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
</ul>
```

its basic dropdown so you have to do a little bit more styling yourself. but here is the css

```
body {    
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 10px;
}

nav ul ul {
display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


nav ul {
     background: red; 
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
content: "";
clear: both;
display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;

}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: black;
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 25px 20px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;

    }


nav ul ul {
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            color: #fff;
        }    
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #000;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}
```

As you can see no class or id's where used.
​